# how to show a message if user navigate away from page

Tags: silverlight

I like to show  warning message if the user attempt to Navigate away from the current page without saving their updates. How can i check if user click other links out of the page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override page's OnNavigatingFrom event and evaluate if form has some pending changes you can set e.Cancel = true that will Cancel out the Navigation request, You can show some Confirmation popup and use its result for e.Cancel.

```
 protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
             var result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Sure", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        e.Cancel = result != MessageBoxResult.OK;
        }
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks but the popup won't waits for user to click a any button(ok or cancel in popup) and then run the rest of the code (after popup.Show();)

Comment: I have added a confirm box in the code above. that is a UI blocking call. If you are using some UserControl(popup) then you will have to make sure that you awaits for the result of the Popup before leaving the ONNavigatingFrom Event. Regards.